# RMarkdown websites: make a dataframe available to several Rmd files?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am sure this should be answered somewhere, but I can not find it...

I am trying to develop a website rendered by `rmarkdown::render_site()` function, and I can not "share" loaded dataframes between the Rmd's files that make up the website.

My files:

_site.yml:

```
name: "my-website"
navbar:
  title: "My Website"
  left:
    - text: "Home"
      href: index.html
    - text: "About"
      href: about.html
```

index.Rmd:

````
---
title: "My Website"
---
Hello, Website!

```{r}
library(data.table)
d <- copy(mtcars)
summary(d)
```
````

about.Rmd:

````
---
title: "About This Website"
---
More about this website.
```{r}
summary(d)
```
````

and render the website by:

```
rmarkdown::render_site()
```

With the following error as an output:

```
|......................                                           |  33%
ordinary text without R code
|...........................................                      |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
Error in summary(d) : object 'd' not found
```

It is obvious that the object d is not available to about.Rmd file during the rendering process...
Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the chunk of the first page

````
```{r,cache=TRUE} 
library(data.table)
d <- copy(mtcars)
summary(d)
```
````

This should create a cache folder in your html folder and make the data from chunk to chunk within the same rMarkdown document available. It allows you to call data in a chunk and use it with in-line r statements throughout the markdown body as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could put

```
library(data.table)
d <- copy(mtcars)
```

in a `global.R` file and use the `source()` function whenever you need `d`.

Comment: Thanks Samuel. Yes, this is a solution for a simple code like `d <- copy(mtcars)`, but in fact the scrip I shoul put in global has lot of lines long, datacrunching a big dataframe, so I do not want to process it as many times as Rmd files I have. If no other solution is available, I will consider this one as a good one but is not an efficient one.

Comment: You could consider writing a script which sources as said and does all the processing and saves it in one place then when you extrude the site the Rmd calls the parts in each page from that initial process without having to call the big file and work on it.

Answer (score 0):

@COLO wrote in a comment

> "in fact the scrip I should put in global has lot of lines long, data crunching a big dataframe, so I do not want to process it as many times as Rmd files I have."

You could save the output of your data crunching to an RDS file with `saveRDS`. Then read it in all other notebooks with

```
df <- readRDS("prepared_data.rds")
```

See [help(readRDS)](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readRDS.html).

Once you have prepared the data for your analysis, reading RDS files tends to be much faster than reading CSV files or waiting for database queries.